# Why do my InnoDB tables keep disappearing? How do I prevent it?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Thank you for your help!

On 2 occasions now, I've had a table almost entirely disappear. The only reason I say almost is because I can't just create a new table with the same name because one already exists. I've had to switch the problem tables to MyISAM to keep going. The first time seemed like a fluke and I didn't think much of it so I don't have much for notes on that one. I'm pretty sure this most recent time occurred during a mysqldump using the options shown here.

```
mysqldump -p --quick --single-transaction
```

Yesterday, I removed two foreign key constraints from the table. It did the same thing to both my test and production databases. Is there anything I can do to prevent problems with this? I would like to be able to keep my tables as InnoDB if possible.

Comment: Are you running MySQL on a case sensitive file system? What is the value of settings regarding case? (`show global variables like 'lower%'`)

Comment: `lower_case_file_system=OFF`, `lower_case_table_names=0`

Comment: Data and tables don't just disappear for no reason. Something's deleting it. MyISAM doesn't have transactions, so maybe you're doing something screwy there. In any case, to find the culprit make a script that watches for missing data and log every query with the [general query logging feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html).

Comment: @tadman My database has a mix of MyISAM and InnoDB tables (something I plan to change). Are you saying that using the `--single-transaction` option could be causing this issue because of the MyISAM tables involved?

Comment: No, I'm saying that MyISAM is an engine you shouldn't be using since it has no journal, no support for transactions, and is missing a ton of integrity features that InnoDB has. If your data is going missing it's highly probable something or someone is deleting it. Turn on general query logging and find out what's being executed when it goes missing. The `--single-transaction` option is used to get a consistent snapshot in time, something MyISAM cannot do. `mysqldump` should not and probably cannot delete data.

Comment: @tadman This is not a clean delete. It only appears to disappear. More likely, it's corrupted to the point that it doesn't register.

Comment: It's quite rare for InnoDB to just lose records like that. What do your server logs say? Is it ever recovering the tables? Is the server being rebooted frequently? Is your backup process causing the main `mysqld` process to hard crash or be killed or a lack of memory? Are your InnoDB settings in `my.cnf` actually broken and causing problems? There's a lot that's potentially going wrong here and none of the signs are good.

Comment: What is the name of a disappearing table?

Comment: @RickJames It's happened to 2 different tables and they're very unique to my db

Comment: @tadman This site is on a GoDaddy CPanel (Shared Hosting) so the server is not restarted frequently and I don't have access to my.cnf. The mysqld process. As far as I can tell, this has never effected the running mysqld.

Comment: I was asking about the names to see if there were any special characters in them that might _somehow_ be causing trouble.

Comment: @RickJames nothing unusual just your basic `a-z_` no keywords either.

Comment: There's two possibilities here: Either you're inadvertently deleting the data and you don't realize it, someone else has access to your control panel and is deleting things, or GoDaddy's server is corrupted. Switching engines should not magically fix anything. There's some deep-rooted problems here you need to diagnose.

Comment: @tadman This is definitely not a manual `DROP` of any kind, either inadvertently by me or by anyone else. It doesn't even act like that. It's more like a ghost table. 99% of the time everything works perfectly. It's only happened twice. Twice is plenty to make me worry though.

Comment: Something sounds highly suspicious. I have my doubts that switching engines will fix it. This is probably a permission problem, you are using shared hosting after all, or perhaps a vulnerability in your code that's being exploited.

Comment: This occurred today in another database on the same machine. It happened when I ran an `ALTER TABLE` to add a column. I got an error that looked like this `#1025 - Error on rename of './database/#sql-2e0f_1254ba7' to './database/table' (errno: 150)` and then the table went ghost.

Answer (score 0):

One user *may* not have permission to see another user's databases.  When you login, do `SHOW GRANTS;` to see if you have `ALL PRIVILEGES` or `SHOW DATABASES` or `SUPER`.  And make sure your grant says `ON *.*`; otherwise the databases are hidden from you, but could still be in existence.

Comment: I'm viewing this with the admin user which has all permissions.